# Unix/Linux Guest Login

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, login

Is there any free *nix guest/guest terminal login without a need to register in order to use it ?

Comment: Could you be more specific? In most distros, there is no guest account by default. What do you mean by register?

Comment: I think he means an online service. Like, a server with SSH access and a guest account you can connect with. Is this what you mean m1k4?

Comment: Yes samjetski, that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My advice is to download [VMware Player](http://vmware.com/products/player/) (presumably for Windows) and use the [Virtual Appliance Marketplace](http://vmware.com/appliances/).  You can get your own Linux virtual machine to use without affecting your host operating system.

I'm not aware of any guest shell accounts.  Too much potential for abuse.